Adding and formatting legends in Show with different kind of graphics
I would like to add a legend to a combination of plots obtained by Show. For example:
Show[{ListPlot[Table[{t, t^2}, {t, -5, 20, 1}], Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.013]], 
  Plot[2 t^2, {t, -5, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thin}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic]}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]

Probably, using Legended is the best way to do this, however I haven't fully understood its syntax. In particular, in the legend

Can I choose a point marker for ListPlot and a line for the Plot?
Can I change the dimension of the point marker and of the line?
Can I control the position of the legend in the plot?
Can I choose to have a framed or not framed legend, with or without a background colour?
Can I choose the font and size of the text inside the legend?
Thanks in advance.


What about the following:
  Show[{
  ListPlot[Table[{t, t^2}, {t, -5, 20, 1}], Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.013],
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[PointLegend[{"  Sample 1"}, LegendMarkers -> Automatic], 
     Scaled[{0.8, 0.1}]]
   ],
  Plot[2 t^2, {t, -5, 20}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thin},
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"Sample 2"}, LegendMarkers -> Automatic], 
     Scaled[{0.8, 0.2}]]]
  }, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]


??
Later edit
To address your question, try this:
Show[{ListPlot[
   Legended[Table[{t, t^2}, {t, -5, 20, 1}], "  Sample 1"], 
   Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.013]], 
  Plot[Legended[2 t^2, "Sample 2"], {t, -5, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thin}]
  }]

yielding the following:

Have a look also at Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/PlotLegends/Scope/LegendPlacement
Have fun!

Is it possible to have the legend also outside the frame of the plot?

@umby Please have a look at the edit.
